# Índice interactivo

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo mi cv en html y quiero hacer un índice interactivo, con esto me refiero a un índice en el cual tengo 4 pestañas las cuales corresponden a 4 partes del cv (ej: datos personales, formación, etc.) y quiero que al tocar una de las pesatañas la página baje hasta esa parte del texto, por ejemplo, una de laa pestañas que tengo es la de "Experiencia", quiero que al tocar esa pestaña la página baje automaticamente hasta donde está el texto con el título "Experiencia". ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Matías, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que crear un enlace interno. Funciona igual que los externos, aunque en vez de referenciar un recurso externo, referencias uno dentro de la página en la que estás:

```
<a href="#datos_personales">Datos Personales</a>
```

Y el punto al que tiene que saltar al hacer click sobre ese enlace tiene que tener ese mismo identificador. Por ejemplo:

```
<h4 id="datos_personales">Datos Personales</a>
```